# Django Models: Automatic field 'modelname_id' is generated

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have been working with from past few month. I saw a weird thing. I have two model like via one to one relationship. one is a core user model and second one is specific user detail model. when i got an attribute error i found an unknown field and when i added it to the admin site in list display i just confused.

see my models below

**models.py**

```
class DocsAppointUserModel(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    type_choices = (
        ('M', 'Moderator'),
        ('D', 'Doctor'),
        ('P', 'Patient'),
        ('A', 'Admin'),
        ('AS','Admin Staff'),
    )
    
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="First Name",default="",max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Last Name",default="",max_length=30)
    user_type = models.CharField(verbose_name="User Type",max_length=2,choices=type_choices,default='P')
    user_email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email",max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    joined_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_active_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) #staff for site admin

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user_email'                                            #for logging it with email
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name","last_name","user_type"]
    objects = UserManager()
    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):              #returns true if the user has specified permission ,
        # print(perm,obj)                                   
        if self.is_superuser:
        
            return True
        else:
            if perm in self.get_user_permissions():
                return True
            else:
                return False 
            
        
        
    def has_module_perms(self,app_Label):                        # return true if any user has permission for a perticular module(app) given 
        if self.is_superuser:
            return True
        else:
            all_perm = list(self.get_user_permissions())
            for i in all_perm:
                if i.split('.')[0]==app_Label:
                    return True
            else:
                return False

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user_email}'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

    def is_patient(self):
        """Return True if User is Patient, else False"""
        return self.user_type == 'P'

    def is_doctor(self):
        """Return True if User is Doctor, else False"""
        return self.user_type == 'D'

    def is_moderator(self):
        """Return True if User is Moderator, eld False"""
        return self.user_type == 'M'

def get_profile_image_upload_path(self,filename):
    return f'profile_images/users/{self.pk}/{filename}'

def get_default_profile_image():
    return f'profile_images/default/profile.png'

class Doctor(models.Model):

    d_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    doctor = models.OneToOneField('DocsAppointUserModel',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_profile_image_upload_path,null=True,blank=True,default=get_default_profile_image)
    specialization = models.CharField('Specialization', max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField("Phone No.",default="",max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField("City",default="",max_length=40)
    state = models.CharField("State",default="",max_length=25)
    address = models.CharField('Address',default="",max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.doctor.first_name} {self.doctor.last_name} - {self.doctor}'
```

See in Doctor model there is no such field like **doctor_id** but it has d_id and it is a primary key field. the auto generated field doctor_id has value of **pk of Docsappointusermodel**
How this field is generated in one to one relationship.
May be i missed something important about django, please help me to understand this concept.

see the admin site below
[image]

Comment: `doctor_id` is let us say the _virtual_ field that Django automatically creates for your field `doctor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model `Doctor` you have a `OneToOneField` with `DocsAppointUserModel` named `doctor`. Hence Django automatically creates a (let us say *virtual*) field which will store the primary key of the related model. This will also be the field which is actually stored in the database.

When you would access `doctor.doctor` you will get the related instance of `DocsAppointUserModel` whereas when you would access `doctor.doctor_id` you would get the primary key of the related `DocsAppointUserModel` i.e. the value of the field `user_email`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt. Could you please share an official document link where this is written!